# Url Rewriting not working

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have something like

```
header('Location:index.php?login_error='.urlencode($error));
```

and i wanna make it

```
header('Location:error/'.urlencode($error));
```

using rewriting. The rule that I am using is

```
RewriteRule ^error/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?login_error=$1 [QSA]
```

but its not working can somebody please guide. Any help shall be highly appreciated.

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^login/?$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ home.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^error/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?login_error=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: Is `urlencode($error)` not containing any characters other than a-z and A-Z? I assume it is, since you're urlencoding it in the first place.

Comment: ya its not redirecting. I get 404

Comment: What's an example URL of `error/whatgoeshere`?

Comment: FYI, you need to use full URLs in `Location:` headers.  While relative paths do generally work, they violate the standards outlined by the RFCs, and you may run into problems at some point.

Comment: h2ooooooo no whatever content $error gets is only restricted to a-z A-Z

Comment: h2ooooooo error/doomed an example

Comment: Can you post your entire `.htaccess` in the main post? FYI: When writing to a user, use an at sign (@) in front of their name. That way they'll get notified.

Comment: @h2ooooooo i have posted my .htaccess

Comment: Does your other redirects work? Are you sure that your `.htaccess` file is in the root directory (same place as the `index.php` file is)?

Comment: @h2ooooooo yup all others are working just cool

Comment: @ShouvikBhattacharya My guess is still that your URL contains some other characters than a-z/A-Z. Could you try to replace the line with `RewriteRule ^error/([^/]+)$ index.php?login_error=$1 [QSA]` instead?

Comment: @h2ooooooo it does work now but the thing is that I want the address bar to look like http://localhost/error/doomed instead it is giving http://localhost/index.php?login_error=doomed

Comment: hey thanks mate i got it working. I am just a beginner great learning for me :)

Comment: @ShouvikBhattacharya Please explain what your problem was and how you fixed it. **Put this info in your original post**. StackOverflow wasn't made to help one person, but rather whoever might search for this same error in the future.

Comment: @h2ooooooo actually your modified rule helped me out I replaced the one with yours and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The OP reported everything working, but it seemed like there was more than the `a-zA-Z` regex in the URL, so a simple rewrite to

```
RewriteRule ^error/([^/]+)$ index.php?login_error=$1 [QSA]
```

did the magic.

`[^/]+` in regex means "any character that isn't a slash repeated 1 or more times"